# Converting string into array containing dictionary

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
[{"leagueId":"37085320-2d31-11e8-802e-c81f66dacb22","leagueName":"Akali's Highwaymen","tier":"BRONZE","queueType":"RANKED_FLEX_SR","rank":"III","playerOrTeamId":"87747329","playerOrTeamName":"REYKKU","leaguePoints":0,"wins":53,"losses":59,"veteran":true,"inactive":false,"freshBlood":false,"hotStreak":false},{"leagueId":"c64de250-0065-11e8-b792-c81f66dd2a8f","leagueName":"Fiora's Horde","tier":"BRONZE","queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","rank":"IV","playerOrTeamId":"87747329","playerOrTeamName":"REYKKU","leaguePoints":28,"wins":29,"losses":25,"veteran":false,"inactive":false,"freshBlood":false,"hotStreak":false}]
```

How do I turn this string into ONE array with dictionary and arrays inside it?

I have tried ast.literal_eval() but that only seems to work when it is ONLY a dictionary

Comment: This looks very much like JSON -> try `json.loads()`, but since the line is relatively long and not broken down, I could have missed something,

Comment: json.loads() seems to work thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `JSON` module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
data = """[{"leagueId":"37085320-2d31-11e8-802e-c81f66dacb22","leagueName":"Akali's Highwaymen","tier":"BRONZE","queueType":"RANKED_FLEX_SR","rank":"III","playerOrTeamId":"87747329","playerOrTeamName":"REYKKU","leaguePoints":0,"wins":53,"losses":59,"veteran":true,"inactive":false,"freshBlood":false,"hotStreak":false},{"leagueId":"c64de250-0065-11e8-b792-c81f66dd2a8f","leagueName":"Fiora's Horde","tier":"BRONZE","queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","rank":"IV","playerOrTeamId":"87747329","playerOrTeamName":"REYKKU","leaguePoints":28,"wins":29,"losses":25,"veteran":false,"inactive":false,"freshBlood":false,"hotStreak":false}]"""
print(json.loads(data))
```

**Output:**

```
[{u'queueType': u'RANKED_FLEX_SR', u'hotStreak': False, u'wins': 53, u'veteran': True, u'losses': 59, u'playerOrTeamId': u'87747329', u'leagueName': u"Akali's Highwaymen", u'playerOrTeamName': u'REYKKU', u'inactive': False, u'rank': u'III', u'freshBlood': False, u'leagueId': u'37085320-2d31-11e8-802e-c81f66dacb22', u'tier': u'BRONZE', u'leaguePoints': 0}, {u'queueType': u'RANKED_SOLO_5x5', u'hotStreak': False, u'wins': 29, u'veteran': False, u'losses': 25, u'playerOrTeamId': u'87747329', u'leagueName': u"Fiora's Horde", u'playerOrTeamName': u'REYKKU', u'inactive': False, u'rank': u'IV', u'freshBlood': False, u'leagueId': u'c64de250-0065-11e8-b792-c81f66dd2a8f', u'tier': u'BRONZE', u'leaguePoints': 28}]
```

Comment: Why did you use 3 """ at the start and at the end? Does that change the data type? Why 3 instead of 1?

Comment: in python triple quotes represent string....`"""String"""` & `'''string'''`

Comment: So what is the difference between "String" and """String"""